# Do Shadowrun limits "belong" to skills or actions that use those skills?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, roll20

So, I'm attempting to fill out a character sheet for Shadowrun 5th Edition on Roll20, and under the "Skills - Active" section, it asks for the "Limit Source" (Physical, Mental, or Social) for the **skill itself**. Now this is somewhat confusing to me, because the Core Rulebook seems to only give limits in the context of performing an action (through a test).

In fact, some skills have different tests that each use a different limit type. A good example of this can be found on page 141 under the section "Using Leadership" where the leader makes a `Leadership + Charisma [Social]` and the target resists with a `Leadership + Willpower [Mental]` test. This implies that skills use different limit types depending on the action being performed with them. Therefore, it seems contradictory to say that the Leadership skill has exactly one "Limit Source".

As best as I can tell, it seems more appropriate to say that each attribute has an associated limit. Skimming through the material reveals that every time the Body, Agility, Reaction, or Strength attribute is used in a test the limit is Physical (if the test uses a limit at all). Tests that involve Willpower, Logic, or Intuition similarly only use the Mental limit. Ditto for Charisma always using the Social limit. This of course ignores when an action uses a special limit such as Accuracy for shooting firearms.

Am I correctly understanding the rationale for which limits apply and when? Is the character sheet on Roll20 misunderstanding what limits get applied to? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 6):

**The limits work how you think they work**

Skill Tests can sometimes use different Limits (this becomes completely clear when looking at spellcasting, where the limit equals the power level you cast the spell at)

**The Character Sheet in Roll20 wants you to change the limit before rolling**

This is the point. You can assign whatever limit you want, and easily change it before rolling. So if you use a skill, before clicking on the roll-button, change the limit to whatever is used in the check.